# importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError when running Python in Docker

Tags: python, docker, python-import, setuptools, python-packaging

I've got the following Docker folder in my project structure

```
.../
docker/
    src/
        my_app/
            __init.py__
            # rest of py files
        my_app_entrypoint.py
        Pipfile
        Pipfile.lock
        pyproject.toml
        setup.cfg
        setup.py
    test/
    build.yaml
    Dockerfile
...
```

My Docker is defined like this:

```
...
COPY src/Pipfile* /home/workspace/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install pipenv \
    && pipenv requirements > requirements.txt \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt
...
COPY src/pyproject.toml ./
COPY src/setup.cfg ./
COPY src/setup.py ./
COPY src/my_app_entrypoint.py ./
COPY src/my_app ./my_app
RUN chmod a+x my_app_entrypoint.py
...
```

and, when running the python code, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/workspace/my_app_entrypoint.py", line 2, in <module>
    import my_app
  File "/home/workspace/my_app/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    __version__ = metadata.version("my_app")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/metadata.py", line 569, in version
    return distribution(distribution_name).version
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/metadata.py", line 542, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/metadata.py", line 196, in from_name
    raise PackageNotFoundError(name)
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: my_app
```

The line `/home/workspace/my_app/__init__.py` that is causing the error is:

```
__version__ = metadata.version("my_app")
```

and my setup.cfg looks like:

```
[metadata]
name = my_app
version = 1.0.0
...

[options]
packages =
    my_app
```

I've tried multiple things but I always get the same error after building the image. It is like it is not recognising the package or the setuptools is not being loaded properly.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? Maybe should I include the `RUN pip install .` in dockerfile after copying the app files in order to install the package?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You can't have both a module (`my_app.py`) and a package (`my_app/__init__.py`) with the exact same name (`my_app`).

Comment: @sinoroc actually, the name of the module is different from the name of the package (I wrote it this way for simplicity, but I have already modified it so that it is all similar)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Yes, `RUN pip install .` was needed in order to install the package!

```
...
COPY src/pyproject.toml ./
COPY src/setup.cfg ./
COPY src/setup.py ./
COPY src/my_app_entrypoint.py ./
COPY src/my_app ./my_app
RUN chmod a+x my_app_entrypoint.py
RUN pip install .
...
```